# PHP $_COOKIE get cookie with preset variable

Tags: php, arrays, cookies, unset

**SOLUTION:**

$_COOKIE was replacing periods with underscores.

```
str_replace('.','-',$cookie_name);
```

**PROBLEM**

I am setting a cookie like this.

```
$cookie_name = '_visited-'.$user_ip.'-'.$visted_link; 
setcookie($cookie_name,'visited',time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
exit;
```

then trying to see if cookie is set and unlink it from links array like this.

```
foreach($links['unique'] as $link){
    $cookie_name = '_visited-'.$user_ip.'-'.$link; 
    if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])){
        if(($key = array_search($l, $links['unique'])) !== false) {
            unset($links['unique'][$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

odd thing is that even though the cookie is clearly set in the foreach using isset I am unable to detect that the cookie exist so I am unable to remove the visited link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so found the issue. I was putting user IP in as part of the cookie name. 
The . was being replaced by _ so just went ahead and replaced all . with - when setting the cookie. Works perfectly as I had intended now.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the cookie on the same page it is set.

As you can see in the [manual](http://php.net/setcookie) it clearly states it:

Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the $_COOKIE array.

Comment: This is requested a separate times. Not on same page after cookie is set the page reloads.

Answer (score 0):

How do you transfer $links from one page to the other?  Each call of the PHP is independent.  That is why I save my cookies to a session table in the database.  First step in each page is to load the sessions from the database.

I think your cookie is never found since $links is initiated at each execution.  Add print_r($links) at the top of the page to see, and edit your question.

Comment: $links['unique'] is created from a list of links stored in my database http://prntscr.com/gqvgh5